# how to select the same content of the field and to delete it in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

```
C:\Users\pengsir>sqlite3  e:\\test.db
sqlite> create table test (f1 TEXT,f2 TEXT, f3 TEXT);
sqlite> insert into test values("x1","y1","w1");
sqlite> insert into test values("x1","y1","w2");
sqlite> insert into test values("x1","y3","w2");
sqlite> insert into test values("x2","y3","w2");
sqlite> insert into test values("x3","y4","w4");
sqlite> insert into test values("x2","y3","w4");
sqlite> insert into test values("x1","y3","w2");
sqlite>
```

1.select the record rows which contain the same f1 and f2 ,and the rowid .

```
sqlite> select rowid,f1,f2 from test group by f1,f2 having(count(f2)>1 and count(f2)>1);

2|x1|y1
7|x1|y3
6|x2|y3
```

I want the result to be :

```
1|x1|y1 
2|x1|y1 
3|x1|y3 
4|x2|y3 
6|x2|y3 
7|x1|y3
```

2.select the record rows which contain the same f1  f2 and f3,and the rowid .

```
sqlite> select rowid,f1,f2,f3 from test group by f1,f2,f3 having(count(f2)>1 and  count(f3)>1);    
7|x1|y3|w2
```

I want the result to be

```
3|x1|y3|w2
7|x1|y3|w2
```

let us discuss this problem further , i want to delete one |x1|y3|w2 and keep one |x1|y3|w2 in the table?here is my method.

```
DELETE FROM test
    WHERE rowid in(
        SELECT rowid FROM test
            WHERE (SELECT count(*)
               FROM test AS t2
               WHERE t2.f1 = test.f1
               AND t2.f2 = test.f2
               AND t2.f3 = test.f3
                   ) >= 2  limit 1);
```

Is there more simple and smart way to do that?  (the method is wrong) 
I find the proper way to do .

```
delete   from test
where    rowid not in
     (
     select  max(rowid)
     from    test
     group by
             f1,f2,f3
     );
```

and the method to more than one duplicate for a f1/f2 combination is :

```
delete from test 
where rowid not in
    (select rowid from test group by f1,f2);
```

It will be executed only one time.

Comment: What do you mean with "the same"? All the f1/f2/f3 values are different in each record!

Comment: no CL,only 3th record is the same as 7th record.

Comment: Put your answer not into the question but into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want records that have duplicates (in those fields), i.e., where the number of records with the same values in those fields is at least two:

```
SELECT rowid, f1, f2
FROM test
WHERE (SELECT count(*)
       FROM test AS t2
       WHERE t2.f1 = test.f1
         AND t2.f2 = test.f2
      ) >= 2
```

This requires executing the subquery for each record.
Alternatively, compute the records with duplicates in a subquery once; this might be more efficient:

```
SELECT test.rowid, test.f1, test.f2
FROM test
JOIN (SELECT f1, f2
      FROM test
      GROUP BY f1, f2
      HAVING count(*) >= 2
     ) USING (f1, f2)
```

---

If you want to remove one of the duplicates, this is easier to do because GROUP BY already returns exactly one output row for each group:

```
DELETE FROM test
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT max(rowid)
                FROM test
                GROUP BY f1, f2
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
```

(If there is more than one duplicate for a `f1`/`f2` combination, you have to execute this multiple times.)

Comment: i want to delete one |x1|y3|w2 and keep one |x1|y3|w2 in the table,my method is as above ,is there more simple and smart way to do that,dear CL.?

Comment: it is a better way to delete records which is more than one duplicate for a f1/f2 combination and it can execute one time to achieve the target,please see the above in my fixed post.my code is smarter than CL's.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SELECT ALL` instead of `SELECT` but according to the [linked docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#distinct) `SELECT` should behave like `SELECT ALL` by default and not like `SELECT DISTINCT` so I don't know where the problem may be.